# dplyr: save count as a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

I used the following to create a dataframe.

```
set.seed(9)
df <- data.frame(
    group=c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
    var1=round(runif(10,1,3),0))
```

Then, I use the following to count number of rows per group:

```
df %>% add_count(group, name="GSIZE")
```

Then, I try to calculate a new variable:

```
df$var2<-df$var1+df$GSIZE
```

That's when I get the error message below:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, var2, value = numeric(0)) : 
>     replacement has 0 rows, data has 10

Any ideas on how to fix this? It seems like GSIZE was not treated as a variable saved in the data frame df.

Comment: df <- df %>% add_count(group, name="GSIZE"). You forget to assign the modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be explicit about an assignment in R. But, for the problem at hand, this suffices.

```
    set.seed(9)
    df <- data.frame(
    group=c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
    var1=round(runif(10,1,3),0)) %>% 
    add_count(group, name="GSIZE") %>% 
    mutate(var2 = var1+GSIZE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 1):

You only counted the rows, but didn't update the `df`. You need to do this.

`df <- df %>% add_count(group, name="GSIZE")`

Then you can use your code, or then use this in `dplyr`

`df %>% mutate(var2 = var1 + GSIZE)`

Which produces:

```
   group var1 GSIZE var2
1      1    1     5    6
2      1    1     5    6
3      1    1     5    6
4      1    1     5    6
5      1    2     5    7
6      2    1     5    6
7      2    2     5    7
8      2    2     5    7
9      2    2     5    7
10     2    3     5    8
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful!